# winston module not behaving properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, flatiron.js, winston

How can I update log file when using Winston to handle logging for node.js. Below is the code which I tried. Only first time the data is getting saved in log file.

```
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
   transports: [
      new (winston.transports.Console)(),
      new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: '2012-07-09.log' })
  ]
});

logger.log('info', 'Test Log Message', { anything: 'This is metadata' });
```

Im using Node version 0.10.10 and winston 0.7.1

Any help on this will be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: This code works fine for me.. tried it twice... got two entries in the log file. What exactly is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Update to winston 7.2
https://github.com/mozilla/persona/commit/ecd695c52d9edbfa46b710ec8832c9fdf890ae16

I use 0.10.24 .It works for me now